# How to the JVM to use a given jaas.conf file?

Tags: java, jvm, jaas

How to I setup the JVM to use a given jaas.conf I created as JAAS setup? Maybe there is a JAAS picks up a configuration property which I can set on startup with `-D`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/yourpathtojaas.conf

Hope this will help you